# How do I remove "Lock Screen Stories" settings option through adb on my Samsung Galaxy device with OneUI/Android 9 Pie

Tags: adb, settings, lockscreen, disable

I have already disabled the "Lockscreen Stories" app through adb. Usually disabling an app also remove the setting associated with it but this time it didn't. The option is stuck there and tapping on it does nothing. I have not tried any except `adb shell dumpsys window windows 'mCurrentFocus'` to possibly find some solution.

**My phone isn't rooted and I'm a beginner**

Comment: This does not seem to be a programming question as described in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You might want to check out [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (be sure to read their corresponding help pages).

Comment: Oh alright. Sorry and thank you